# Creating grpc client request with repeated fields

Tags: go, grpc-go

I have proto file like this:

```
message StartAssignmentRequest {
  string additional_comment = 3;
  repeated RideSlip slips = 4;
}


message RideSlip{
  string slip_name = 2;
  string slip_ext = 3;
  string slip_link = 4;
}
```

Now I want to create its request and I am doing something like this:

```
req := &api.StartAssignmentRequest{
    AdditionalComment:"AdditionalComment",
    Slips: &api.RideSlip[],
}
```

but not having idea how I can send RideSlip data properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protobuffer (both 2 and 3) `repeated` fields are [compiled to slices](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/go-generated#repeated) in Go.

Just `append` to it:

```
req := &api.StartAssignmentRequest{
    AdditionalComment: "AdditionalComment",
}

req.Slips = append(req.Slips, &api.RideSlip{
    SlipName: "foo",
    SlipExt: "bar",
    SlipLink: "https://stackoverflow.com",
})
```

Or assign to it a [literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) value:

```
req := &api.StartAssignmentRequest{
    AdditionalComment: "AdditionalComment",
    Slips: []*api.RideSlip{
        {
            SlipName: "foo",
            SlipExt: "bar",
            SlipLink: "https://stackoverflow.com",
        },
    },
}
```